# How to cancel a countdown timer when a notification is clicked?

Tags: android, timer, notifications

I know this has been asked a million times in other forums, but I haven't got a perfect answer yet. This is my requirement:

When the activity goes to bacground, the timer starts and after 10 sec the notification appears. If the user doesn't click on the notification after 10 sec  the notification changes. 
When the user clicks on the first notification, the last viewed screen appears - i.e the activity comes to the foreground. This is achieved by:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(TimedAlert.this, FirstActivity.class);

notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

But i want the timer to stop immediately after the activity comes to foreground. I.e in `onResume ()` I give `timer.cancel()` but this doesn't seem to work. I also tried `onNewIntent()` but it works only when I am on the first activity when the app goes to background from the second activity. On coming to foreground the `onNewIntent()` method is not called, even though I have given single top for the second activity.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: please someone help me ... i am a complete new bie ..

Answer (score 0):

when the user click on the `Notification`, the system will call your `notificationIntent`, in your case the system will start `FirstActivity`, then in your `FirstActivity` you can stop the count down.

Comment: Thanx for d response ..But am facing 2 issues :- firstly----When the notification is clicked , it goes to onResume of the First activity ..i am not able to cancel the timer in onResume() method          Secondly----it need not go to first activity always ,goes to the activity on top of the stack ,i.e the screen from where the user switches to another application ....hope i am clear ... kindly help